# Docker: what is the difference in docker ps output between 123-125/tcp and 0.0.0.0:123-125->123-125/tcp notations?

Tags: docker, containers, port

After starting docker container with standart command ...

```
docker run -p 123-125:123-125 -it <container_name> "bin/bash"
```

... and exiting it with CTRL-P + CTRL-Q, I noticed that suddenly I see 2 blocks in port column of **docker ps** output:

> 100-102/tcp, 0.0.0.0:123-125:123-125/tcp

I was never setting 100-102 ports for my container.

I cannot get 2 things:

1. what is the difference between these 2 notations: 100-102/tcp and 0.0.0.0:123-125:123-125/tcp in docker ps output?
2. why I have additional 100-102/tcp output in docker ps if my -p parameter was only listing 123-125:123-125/tcp?

Comment: I am not sure why `100:102/tcp` mapping originated. Although the base image of your image could have suggested `102` port in `EXPOSE`, it should not get exposed unless you explicitly specify it with `docker run -p 100:102`. I assume this mapping could be caused accidentaly by the incorrect three colon syntax in your `-p` option.

Comment: Just for clarity, it should be `<image_name>` instead of `<container_name>` in your docker run example.

Comment: When you EXPOSE in the Dockerfile, exposed port do appear even if not published/bound. See my answer @user14967413

Comment: @Faeeria OP says he see `100:102/tcp` mapping. `EXPOSE` in Dockerfile defines only container port (`102`). Where does the host port `100` come from then?

Comment: @Faeeria You could even try to define `EXPOSE 1234` in an example Dockerfile and running the image. Without explicitly publishing the port, you will see `1234/tcp` in docker ps output, i.e. only the container port, not the host port.

Comment: I am pretty sure the actual result from his `docker ps` is `100-102/tcp` and that he also ran his container with `-p 123-125:123-125`, and that it comes from a mistype in his question. If not, he would have a whole different error and would have asked about this error, and would not have been able to connect to his container. I am answering his question : what is the difference between exposing and publishing.

Comment: Also, running `-p 123-125:123:125 ` would not accidentaly bind port `100` to port `102`. It would just cause an error. There no magic there.

Comment: Sorry for misprint!  I used correct syntax in my command: -p 123-125:123:125, but I amde a typo in the question.

Comment: Faeeria, actually result of docker ps is both: "100-102/tcp, 0.0.0.0:123-125:123-125/tcp"

Comment: Yup. See my answer :)

Comment: So do you get the difference between exposed and published ? @MiamiBeach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameters are the ports **exposed** by your container. They were probably exposed in the Dockerfile used to create the image. They are only a kind of specification/documentation telling you you should probably publish those ports.

The second parameters are the exposed ports that you bound to your host system : those portsare linked to ports from your host, and they are open to outside connections coming from any IP address (0.0.0.0). These ports are **published** (thus the `-p`)

If you had run your container with the `-P` options, it would have published/bound all of the exposed ports (or port range, in your case). Publishing ports with `-p` only expose and bind the ports you specify with that options. Which is what you want here.

Here is an example to be clearer :

1. I create a `Dockerfile`. In it I expose the port range 3000-3002

```
FROM node:current-alpine

EXPOSE 3000-3002/tcp

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

2. I build the image : `docker build -t testing .`
3. I run a container : `docker run testing`

Here is the result of `docker ps` :

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                 [...] PORTS           NAMES
59b8a12a8d70   testing   "docker-entrypoint.s…"  [...] 3000-3002/tcp   amazing_gagarin
```

As you can see, I didn't publish any ports, but I can see my exposed ports in the `PORTS` section of `docker ps`

4. I try to connect to `localhost:3000` : nothing works -> the ports aren't published.
5. I launch another container with `docker run -p 3005-3007:3005-3007 testing`.

Here is the result of `docker ps` :

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                 [...] PORTS                                             NAMES
d55dd52d94a3   testing   "docker-entrypoint.s…"  [...] 3000-3002/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3005-3007->3005-3007/tcp   agitated_boyd
```

6. I try to connect to `localhost:3005` : it works ! -> I published my ports, binding them to my host ports, so I can connect to them (also because my app does listen to ports from 3000-3007)
7. I try to connect to `localhost:3000` : it still does not work -> the port range 3000-3002 is still not published, but is still marked as exposed, telling me that I might want to use this range.

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you, Faeeria!

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Docker ref](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports) for the format of `-p` option:
`format: ip:hostPort:containerPort | ip::containerPort | hostPort:containerPort | containerPort`

1. `0.0.0.0` specifies the IP from which your container can be accessed on the host. `0.0.0.0` is the default and means all IP addresses (i.e. everybody connecting to your host can access your container via exposed ports 123-125). On the other hand, `127.0.0.1` would mean you can access your container only from localhost.
2. I assume the additional port could be exposed by your base image (defined in `FROM` in your Dockerfile).

Btw, I am not sure if your syntax `0.0.0.0:123-125:123:125` with three colons is correct.

Comment: Their syntax is correct : see the question title. It's only a mistype in the question body.

Answer (score 0):

The publish option (-p) is not following any of the allowed formats:

> ip:hostPort:containerPort | ip::containerPort | hostPort:containerPort
> | containerPort

The given run command has 3 colon - but the first part is not an IP. So, I believe that Docker is not taking your command well.

The correct run command, if you want to match container ports 123..125 to the corresponding host portsm is:

```
docker run -p 123-125:123-125 -it <container_name> "bin/bash"
```

Comment: Their syntax is correct : see the question title. It's only a mistype in the question body.

Comment: Faeeria is right. But - good catch, Charlie!